# Get Display names of Direct reportees in Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, react

I need to get display names for all the direct reportees under a manager. I am using below code to get direct reporteees using rest in SPFx using react.

```
public componentDidMount(){
    this.getReportees();
}
getReportees = () => {
    var reportees = [];
    var reactHandler = this;
    var drReportess = [];
    $.ajax({
      url: this.siteUrl+"/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)?@v='" + encodeURIComponent(accountName) + "'&$select=DirectReports",
      method: "GET",
      headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
    }).done((data)=>{
      let length: Number = data.d.DirectReports.results.length > 0 ? data.d.DirectReports.results.length : 0;
      if(length>0){
        $.each(data.d.DirectReports.results, function (i, value: string) {
          reportees.push(value);
        });
        $.each(reportees,function(i,value){
          $.ajax({
            url:  this.siteUrl+"/_api/SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetUserProfilePropertyFor(accountName=@v,propertyName='PreferredName')?@v='" + encodeURIComponent(value) + "'",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
          }).done((data)=>{
            drReportess.push({
              DisplayName: data.d.GetUserProfilePropertyFor,
              LoginName: value
            })
          })
        })
        reactHandler.setState({
          directReportees: drReportess
        })
        console.log(reactHandler.state.directReportees);
      } 
    })
  }
public render(): React.ReactElement<IDashboardProps> {
   console.log('Render');
   return(
   <table className="ms-Table course-table">
      <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>Team Members</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {this.state.directReportees && this.state.directReportees.map((item, i) => {
       return [
          <tr>
              <td>{item.DisplayName}</td>
           </tr>
        ]
       })}
       </tbody>
   </table>
);
}
```

problem with this code is the render function is loading first (console.log) before completing the rest call so table is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can call your render function after the page loaded completely like below :

```
$(document).ready(function()

 { 

  // Your render function or code should be here. 


 });
```

Note :

- The above code is needed jquery library and this demerit as well, this document.Ready is supposed to load the page first, then inside code should be executed but this is not consistent... varies browser to browser.. does not work across the all browsers.

As an alternative, you can use the below javascript code :

```
setTimeout(function()
{ 
 // Your render function or code should be here. 
}, 3000);
```

**OR**

```
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
{

  // Your render function or code should be here. 

 }, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. i have updated complete code block, any other approach other than timeout?

Answer (score 0):

You could call your function in React lifecycle method componentDidMount().
[image]

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this getReportees  method is called inside componentDidMount only.

Comment: try to add async:false to change both ajax request to synchronize